# Is it legal to replace something's firmware?

Tags: software, hacking, hardware

I'm a software/hardware hacker and I am wondering about how legal it is to replace the firmware of something. This something can be

- a car
- a chinese quadcopter
- a phone
- a Canon EOS 5D
- a (connected) digital thermometer
- a presence sensor
- … anything.

I know that *modify* the firmware may be illegal (because of licensing/copying copyrights, usually).

But what if you can't even read the firmware, only replace it with one your wrote yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's yours - do what you like with it

Assuming that you are the legal owner of the device then you are entitled to do whatever you like with it: smash it with a sledgehammer, brush your teeth with it, upload firmware, etc.

**Unless**, what you would like to do is otherwise illegal ...

### Copyright

It is unlikely that in buying the item you also bought the copyright in the firmware. More likely you have a licence to use it and that permission is limited to what the licence allows.

So, *if* you can write the firmware without using their firmware as a starting point then you can upload your new firmware. Personally, I think it would be next to impossible to build working firmware without knowing what their firmware does but if you can do so: well done.

### Regulatory

Some of the things you name require government regulated designs - cars and telephones spring to mind. Your firmware is not part of that government approval so, for example, you couldn't drive a modified car on a public road, or connect a modified telephone to a telecommunications carrier without getting those approvals.

Comment: Errh, is Australia really that harsh? We can drive modified cars over here, apart from basis structural requirements like the requirement for bumpers, hoods, brakes.

Comment: @user6726 Modified vehicles (other than "cosmetic" modifications like, spoilers, sunroofs etc.) require an engineer's certificate to be registered for the first time (a "blue slip" - you also need a "pink slip" for a mechanic's check if the vehicle is over 3 years old and a "green slip" which is evidence of your 3rd party personal injury insurance - the colour names date from when they were actual pieces of paper of those colours, nowadays they are electronic and have no colour). Changing firmware would definitely require a blue slip.